# write newline in a file using R5RS scheme

Tags: scheme, r5rs

I've been looking for a way to write a newline in a file
I have to use R5RS, I saw in a previous question (newline port) but this doesn't work in this version, neither does the \n,

any ideas?

everything is being written in a single line
(write "hello" p)
(write "w" p)

gives me a file with hellop

Comment: Could you please specify which Scheme system you are using?

Answer (score 5):

If your I/O functions don't allow you to specify a port, you may be able to use `with-output-to-file` instead:

```
(with-output-to-file "test.out"
  (lambda ()
    (display "Hello, world!")
    (newline)))
```